# How to refer to previous answer as the deafult value of a next question?

Tags: python

Consider the following example:

```py
import questionary

answers = questionary.form(
    first = questionary.text("Hi?"),
    second = questionary.text("Hi again?", default=lambda x: x['first'])
).ask()
```

I am trying to use the answer of `first` as the default answer for `second`. How to do?

Comment: A quick scan of the documentation doesn't suggest there is a way to do this.

Comment: I'd suggest filing this as a question on the github repo https://github.com/tmbo/questionary
The authors of the library are far more likely to have suggestions or workarounds.